# A word that means upload one's work to different platforms

Tags: word-request

I'm sorry that I don't even remember its exact definition, otherwise I would've googled it out.

I just came across the word *contribute*, then it triggered my memory of the word I don't remember.

The verb means something like *"to upload/distribute/send one's work to various platforms/agents in order to get exposure."* The word is quite common I suppose..

Sorry for such a vague request but I really want to know the word, anybody?

Comment: Could you be thinking of the word "distribute"?

Comment: Or even just "publish?" (Although that means to expose a work to the general public, not to agents who may or may not publish the work for you.)

Comment: A pejorative word would be "spam", implying that they sent it to many different places, regardless of how appropriate it is.  For example, "We're a sports journalism website and this guy just sent us a movie review. He must be **spamming** it out to everyone."

Comment: @RobJarvis No it's not distribute

Comment: @TypeIA nah it's not, I remember quite clearly that in the dictionary it says to send sth to various programmes/platforms..

Comment: Was it disseminate?

Comment: @Jack O'Flaherty NO.. I think it starts with S but I'm not sure

Comment: One more guess... circulate?

Comment: Bulk **Submission** :)

Comment: hhhhhh @TypeIA I like that, but it's not circulate, it starts with S I suppose.. anyway I kinda gave up on it, maybe I'll see it again one day, thanks typelA~

Comment: It could be **submit** which really means, in this context, "to offer for consideration": (it has several other meanings in other contexts) but is often used for the act of clicking the button that uploads a post or puts a contribution on a platform.

Comment: Crosspost? Simulcast?

Answer (score 1):

Some possibilities:

- distribute
- disseminate
- publish
- shop around
- make public
- release